# Using EJBQL with EntityQuery jboss seam

Tags: java, seam2

I have a method that receives a lot of params and should use this in a query, EJBQL query. With normal query I can use:

```
public void method(Long code){
Query q = this.em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ClassA a WHERE a.code = :code);        q.setParameter("code", code);
}
```

This works very well. But change this to EJBQL dont work as I expected:

```
public void method(Long code){
        EntityQuery<Object> eq = new EntityQuery<Object>();
        eq.setEjbql("SELECT a FROM ClassA a WHERE a.code = :code");
        //Set here the param code
        }
```

My EntityQuery is from: org.jboss.seam.framework

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't new entityQuery use this

```
EntityManager em = (EntityManager) Expressions.instance().createValueExpression("#{entityManager}").getValue();

em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ClassA a WHERE a.code = :code);
```